# Java - receive a method that takes any number/type of parameters as method parameter

Tags: java, callback

I'm implementing a Console Menu class in Java, roughly it looks like this:

```
public class ConsoleMenu {
    private Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    private ArrayList<String> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();

    
    public void addMenuItem(String description) {
        // ... adds item to the menu
    }

    public void displayMenu() {
        // ... displays the menu
    }

    public int getUserChoice() {
        // ... get the user's choice and returns it.
    }

}
```

Currently, the class displays the main to the user as such:

```
1. Add item to shopping list
2. Delete item from shopping list
3. Save shopping list
4. Exit
```

When the user chooses, the `getUserChoice` returns the number of the choice (1, 2, 3 or 4).
But what I would like is that instead of having a list of `String`s, I would like each menu item to be represented by an instance of `ConsoleMenuItem` which holds the description as String, and a callback method, and then have the `getUserChoice` method to call that callback method.

So, I would like the `addMenuItem` method take a callback method as a parameter, as well as  any number/types of parameters that needs to be passed to this callback method.

What I've managed to come up with is:

```
class ConsoleMenuItem {
    private String description;
    private Consumer<Object[]> function;
    private Object[] args;

    ConsoleMenuItem(String description, Consumer<Object[]> function, Object... args) {
        this.description = description;
        this.function = function;
        this.args = args;
    }

    void execute() {
        this.function.accept(this.args);
    }

}

public class ConsoleMenu {
    private Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    private ArrayList<ConsoleMenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();


    public void addMenuItem(String description, Consumer<Object[]> function, Object... args) {
        menuItems.add(new ConsoleMenuItem(description, function, args));
    }

    public void displayMenu() {
        // display the menu
    }

    public void getUserChoice() {
        // 
    }

}
```

The problem with this approach is that it can only take callback methods with the following signature: `void someMethod(Object[] args)`.  How can I make it so that any method can be passed as a callback?

Comment: Why a callback function?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really any point in providing the function and arguments separately because you don't actually use them separately.

You may as well just pass in a `Runnable`. That takes no arguments when you actually invoke it, but you can bind in whatever arguments you need when you construct it.

For example, instead of:

```
new ConsoleMenuItem("description", function1, arg1, arg2);
new ConsoleMenuItem("description", function2, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

You can do:

```
new ConsoleMenuItem("description", () -> function1(arg1, arg2));
new ConsoleMenuItem("description", () -> function2(arg1, arg2, arg3));
```

You also benefit from type checking by doing this, because you aren't forced to accept `Object` for your arguments to the functions.

Comment: How does the ConsoleMenuItem constructor looks this way?

Comment: `ConsoleMenuItem(String description, Runnable runnable)`.